# Convert Live Data to kotlin flow in jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, kotlin-flow

Hey I am new in jetpack compose. I am checking in internet is available or not and consume through live data. Now I started learning jetpack compose so I want to use Flow, So any guys help me to convert this LiveData to flow and use in jetpack compose.

**NetworkConnection.kt**

```
import android.app.Application
import android.content.Context
import android.net.ConnectivityManager
import android.net.Network
import android.net.NetworkRequest
import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData

class NetworkConnection(private val connectivityManager: ConnectivityManager) : LiveData<Boolean>() {

    constructor(application: Application) : this(application.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager)

    private val networkCallback = object : ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback() {
        override fun onAvailable(network: Network) {
            super.onAvailable(network)
            postValue(true)
        }

        override fun onLost(network: Network) {
            super.onLost(network)
            postValue(false)
        }
    }

    override fun onActive() {
        super.onActive()
        val builder = NetworkRequest.Builder()
        connectivityManager.registerNetworkCallback(builder.build(), networkCallback)
    }

    override fun onInactive() {
        super.onInactive()
        connectivityManager.unregisterNetworkCallback(networkCallback)
    }

}
```

Can someone help me which way of doing recommendations for kotlin flow in jetpack compose.

**MainActivity.kt**

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {

    private lateinit var checkNetworkConnection: NetworkConnection

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        checkNetworkConnection = NetworkConnection(application)
        setContent {
            SportsResultTheme {
                SetupView()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am confused also how can I use flow in my compose in recommendation way. Thanks

Comment: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/libraries#streams

Answer (score 1):

Jetpack compose has function (LiveData.observeAsState()) available to [convert LiveData to State](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state#use-other-types-of-state-in-jetpack-compose) that you can use in your Compose UI. You don't have to use Flow if you already have a LiveData in your code base. Pass your live data into the composable and convert it to a state. You can also convert live data to state before you call the `SetupView` composable and just pass the state itself.

```
@Composable
fun SetupView(networkConnection : NetworkConnection) {
    val isConnected = networkConnection.observeAsState()
    
    if(isConnected) {
        // update for connected state
    } else {
        // handle offline state
    }
}
```

Comment: Can this be done in a ViewModel?  It has to be inside a `Composable` function.

Answer (score 1):

NetworkConnection.kt ->

```
    class NetworkConnection(private val connectivityManager: ConnectivityManager) {

    init {
        registerNetworkCallback()
    }

    constructor(application: Application) : this(application.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager)

    val stateFlow: StateFlow<State>
        get() = _stateFlow

    private val _stateFlow: MutableStateFlow<State> = MutableStateFlow(State.Init)

    private val networkCallback = object : ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback() {
        override fun onAvailable(network: Network) {
            super.onAvailable(network)
            _stateFlow.value = State.Available
        }

        override fun onLost(network: Network) {
            super.onLost(network)
            _stateFlow.value = State.Gone
        }
    }

    fun registerNetworkCallback(){
        val builder = NetworkRequest.Builder()
        connectivityManager.registerNetworkCallback(builder.build(), networkCallback)
    }

    fun unregisterNetworkCallback() {
        connectivityManager.unregisterNetworkCallback(networkCallback)
    }

    sealed interface State {
        object Init : State
        object Available : State
        object Gone : State
    }

}
```

MainActivity.kt

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {

    private lateinit var checkNetworkConnection: NetworkConnection

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        checkNetworkConnection = NetworkConnection(application)
        setContent {
            SportsResultTheme {
            checkNetworkConnection.stateFlow.collectAsState()
                SetupView()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: where are you calling `unregisterNetworkCallback()` function ?

Comment: It depends on design and requirement, if you want to unregister on lifecycle events `LifecycleEventObserver { _, event ->}` can be used.

Comment: I would also encourage using `ViewModel`.

Comment: Can you please give be viewmodel example?

Comment: Just use normal ViewModel, and declare a `State/MutableState`
`val state = mutableStateOf(State.Init)`
In you compose, you can observe state like `viewModel.state`
Please refer to Android doc. for more details. 
https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state

Comment: It is better to do any network-related code in a ViewModel instead of Activity.